# Xcode 5.1 Building Wrong TestFlight SDK

Tags: ios, xcode5, testflight

Since the latest Xcode 5.1 and adding TestFlight 3.0 to my project, Xcode keeps building the project with the old 2.02 version of TestFlight.
 Clean builds don't seem to help. Where else could it be picking this up from ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a stale search path reference hanging around (ie deleting the folder from the project did not remove the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` entry). So there were two ways to find libTestFlight.a and it was using the first, wrong, one. Search for `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` in your Build Settings, and if there's an unwanted old entry still there, get rid of it!